# remove part of url via mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any way to hide part of a Url via mod_rewrite. I am currently using part of the url, .htm, to split the page that is being requested and the query string.

Example

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single.htm/articleid=8
```

This would let me know that the page requested is:

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single
```

And the quest string is:

```
article=8
```

Ideally i would like the have this to work the same url without the .htm visible

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single/articleid=8
```

The number of variables in the query sting varies as does the number of levels before the .htm so the rule would need to be dynamic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also do multiple querystring parameters, how do you want it to look? I started with this, which keeps this simple, then got trickier below.

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single/articleid=8&anothervar=abc
```

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)/(.+)$ $1.htm?$2 [NC,L]
```

This handles one or more querystring parameters, but does require at least one. This looks for anything without an `=` up to a slash, then everything else. Basically, it uses the `=` as the indicator of the path vs. the querystring portions; but actually splits it on the slash. (The NC is a habit of mine; not needed in this case, but when I leave it out I forget it when it's needed.)

To let querystrings be optional, so it could handle just

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single
```

I found it easiest with two rules, instead of trying to mingle this into one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)/(.+)$ $1.htm?$2 [NC,L]
```

You can do something even prettier, using slashes for everything including multiple querystring parameters, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page/article/single/articleid=8/anothervar=abc
```

It's a little hairy, but I think this works (couldn't let it go...)

Another rule handles replacing the slashes with ampersands, then doing the rewrite as above. This was easier to keep straight - maybe there's a way to do it all at once, but this was tricky enough for me:

```
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)/([^=]+=[^/]+)/([^=]+=.+)$ $1/$2&$3 [NC,LP]
RewriteRule ^/([^=]+)/(.+)$ /$1.htm?$2 [NC,L]
```

The first rule is as above, handling no querystrings at all. That just gets it out of the way.

The second rule is a loop `LP`, which is what I tend to find in examples whenever you have an unknown number of replacements. In this case, it's replacing the last querystring-slash with an ampersand, and looping until there's only one left (leaving that for the question mark in the third rule).

It's looking for the last one of these `articleid=8/anothervar=abc` where there are two parameters left. It replaces the slash with an ampersand like `articleid=8&anothervar=abc`

In words, it's looking for (and capturing in parentheses):

```
(not-equalsign) slash (not-equalsign equalsign not-slash) slash (not-equalsign equalsign anything)
```

This lines up as:

```
(not-equalsign)                       /page/article/single
slash                                 /
(not-equalsign equalsign not-slash)   articleid = 8
slash                                 /
(not-equalsign equalsign anything)    anothervar = abc
```

It replaces the last slash with an ampersand, and after looping, turns it into the first draft above: `http://www.example.com/page/article/single/articleid=8&anothervar=abc` . The third rule handles this as described above.

A note: These also assume all your urls will look like this, since they're going to tack on .htm to everything. If you want still allow explicit `/something/page.htm` then these rules would need to not-match on .htm if it's already there - something like that. Or maybe an initial rule up front that looks for .htm and just stops rewriting there. Or maybe only do this for the /page paths.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I have got something working using a combination of the first and second rule just need to run some testing on it now.